# plots after dynamic sections using R Markdown pander, knitr and pandoc

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, pander

I use this rmd:

````
---
title: "Some Title"
author: "Some Author"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d-%m-%Y')`" 
---

## A function that generates sections

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(pander)

create_section <- function() {

   # Inserts "## Title (auto)"
   pander::pandoc.header('Title (auto)', level = 2)

   # Section contents
   # e.g. a random plot
   plot(sample(1000, 10))

   # a list, formatted as Markdown
   # adding also empty lines, to be sure that this is valid Markdown
   pander::pandoc.p('')
   pander::pandoc.list(letters[1:3])
   pander::pandoc.p('')
}
```

## Generate sections

```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
n_sections <- 3

for (i in seq(n_sections)) {
   create_section()
}
```
````

and then:

```
library(knitr);
library(rmarkdown);

setwd("C:/bla")

knit('test_md.Rmd')
rmarkdown::pandoc_convert("test_md.md", to = "pdf", output = "test_pdf.pdf")
```

This kind of works but the plots are all rendered after the sections:

[image]

Each section should contain the plot. Any ideas? Thanks!

PS:

Wrapping:

```
plot(sample(1000, 10))
```

in print:

```
print(plot(sample(1000, 10)))
```

forces output to be produced. Unfortunately, NULL is also printed underneath the plot.

Comment: Sometimes you need line break between your sections, have the plot on its own line with each line above and below empty

Comment: thanks. do you mean line break in the source code? just tried and did not make a difference ...

Answer (score 0):

Could you just add `pdf_document` in the YAML and then generate the PDF by knitting?

```
---
title: "Some Title"
author: "Some Author"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d-%m-%Y')`" 
output: pdf_document
---
```

[image]

I was able to get the same result you described when running the `rmarkdown::pandoc_convert()` on the .md file, all the plots at the end of the .PDF file.

Comment: thanks this does not work easier. Maybe it is because I use Windows and Miketex